# Sending parameter form applet to a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, applet

I am doing a program where user data will be accessible form a applet only.

In my program I want to get the data(String parameter) from a applet and from applet I want to send it to a servlet. But I dont know why my servlet is not getting called. I am using GET method.

Bellow I am attaching my code.

Applet Code where I calling the servlet:

```
System.out.println("codebase"+getCodeBase());
URL postURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/AppletExample/myServlet");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) postURL.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write("param1="+alias);
out.flush();
```

The Servlet code is:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("name value is");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String name=request.getParameter("param1");
    System.out.println("name value is"+name);
}
```

Please give any solution.

Comment: `URL postURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/AppletExample/myServlet");` 1) That won't work any time but during development. 2) If it is the same server as the applet, it is better (in terms of security) to form the URL relative the the document or code base of the applet.  It is also more portable.

Answer (score 0):

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                     conn.getOutputStream());
```

replace above code with your

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
```

this may work .